# vscode extension: programmatically opening multiple files for reading only

Tags: vscode-extensions

my vscode extension has a list of workspace files that should *all* be opened in the text editor, using `showTextDocument`....  i'm finding that only the *last* file in the set is actually shown in an editor tab....

i'm *not* interested in splitting the screen into "one-group-per-file"

if i do this manually, of course, i need to "double-click" the files to ensure they are *not* in preview mode; otherwise, the tab is simple replaced....  i can also manually use the `Pin` action on the tab's context menu....

but i want to do this programmatically, and am not sure how to execute the equivalent of the `Pin` action in my extension.... in reality, i would like multiple editor tabs that are each "readonly"....

suggestions???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a file read-only in the session (i.e., not in the fileSystem) try running this when that file is the active editor:

```js
vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.files.setActiveEditorReadonlyInSession');
```

---

For why only the last file shown is visible, do you have the `preview` option set to false in the `TextDocumentShowOptions`?

You should use a version of `showTextDocument()` that can take a `TextDocumentShowOptions` argument.  And in that argument set `preview` and `preserveFocus` to `false`.

```js
const showOptions: vscode.TextDocumentShowOptions = { preserveFocus: false, preview: false, etc. }
```

Comment: where did you find the 'workbench.actions.file ...' command???  i didn't see it the list within the extension docs....

Comment: @biosbob Commands that are in the `Keyboard Shortcuts` can also be run in an extension using that `executeCommand()` method.  Also commands in https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands